How to get all UI control a given property is bounded to WPF C#
I am using reflection to get a list of properties and I would like to use the property to get the instance(s) of the WPF control the given property is bounded to.
So in the code behind I would like to access the control in the code behind using only the Property name. In the list of properties I could have property 'String Name' which is bound to a 'Textbox' I would like to access the Textbox. and in the example below I would like access to the Listbox.
C#:
private ObservableCollection<Show> _Shows;
[ReportableProperty]
public ObservableCollection<Show> Shows
{
    get { return _Shows; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _Shows)
        {

            _Shows = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Shows");
        }
    }
}

XAML:
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Shows, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTip="Test" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedShows, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="lstShows" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValuePath="id" SelectionChanged="lstShows_SelectionChanged"></ListBox>


Just to clarify your difficult to read question: you have an object that serves as a binding source. Now you want to use reflection to get all properties of that binding source. Next, for each obtained property name you want to get all controls that are currently binding to that property? Is this correct?

@BionicCode Yes, thats correct. Precisely that.

In this case, you must understand how data bindig works. A binding is always set on the binding target (which is always a dependency property). This means, the only information about a Binding is stored with the dependency property of the binding target. It's impossible to get that information from the binding source. As a consequence, you would have to get all controls and check all dependency properties of each control to collect all binding expressions.

Then you have to get the binding source of the expression and match that against your predicate source object that you are using reflection on. If you find a match then try to match the binding path of the current dependency property. If you have a match, then you have found your control. Then continue with the next dependency property and after all properties of the current control go to the next control and repeat. You have to repeat that complete procedure for all source properties (PropertyInfo pbjects).This is a very expensive task.

This brings up the question why you want to do this? Maybe there is a better solution to your original problem.

@BionicCode I need to create a function that gets all the reportable properties and stores/maps its UI elements against its property. e.g. String Name will have against it the Width = 50 the width data can be hardcoded or bound to the same object but my reflection is not picking it up because it's not a reportable property. It's to keep track/audit(more like a snapshot) of the reportable elements that get added/removed from the window().

"String Name will have against it the Width = 50" - Can you elaborate more on this? And where is the difference between properties that are annotated with an attribute and those that are not?

@BionicCode
"String Name will have against it the Width = 50" - What I meant is Width is a UI attribute and in an object called 'ReportResult' the reportable property Name will be stored in  'public string PropertyName { get; set; }' and the corresponding UI attributes and value like 'Width' will be stored in ' public List<Dictionary<string, string>> SelectedUIAttributesandValues { get; set; }'

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@BionicCode "Then you have to get the binding source of the expression and match that against your predicate source object " This is the bit I can find the code for.

Your original problem is not clear to me. So I can provide you with a solution for what you have asked for. Because of the performance intensive nature of the solution, it's worth trying to solve your original problem differently, e.g. by improving your design. I can't help you with this as I don't understand the original problem you are trying to solve.
The point is that you can't get binding targets from a binding source as the complete binding metadata is stored with the binding target.

You will have to get all controls that are a potential binding target.
From this collection of potential binding targets, you pick an object one-by-one.
Get all dependency properties of the object.
Get the BindingExpression of each obtained dependency property (a collection of BindingExpression objects).
From the collection of BindingExpression objects, take a BindingExpression one-by-one to check if a binding is using your provided property name as a binding source.
If you have a list of property names, then repeat 5) for all properties (nested loop)
Next, if you have a list of source objects then repeat from 5) (nested loop)
Repeat from 3) for all potential binding targets (nested loop)

You can see that there are a lot of nested loops (at least three) that make the algorithm very costly. In addition, you have to use reflection for every step. That's why you should try to solve the original problem more gracefully.
The following example shows how to get the dependency properties of a potential binding target (DependecyObject) and inspects the binding of each property. Each binding target that has a binding to the provided source object is collected (there can be multiple targets using the same source).
You would have to extend the helper method with the code that generates a collection of potential controls that you want to inspect and a collection of source objects, each with a list of property names.
private readonly Dictionary<DependencyObject, IEnumerable<BindingExpression>> bindingExpressionsMap = new();

public bool TryGetBindingTargets(
  Type bindingSourceType, 
  string sourcePropertyName, 
  IEnumerable<DependencyObject> candidates, 
  out IEnumerable<DependencyObject> bindingTargets)
{
  var identifiedBindingTargets = new List<DependencyObject>();

  foreach (DependencyObject candidate in candidates)
  {
    if (this.bindingExpressionsMap.TryGetValue(candidate, out IEnumerable<BindingExpression> bindingExpressions))
    {
      foreach (BindingExpression bindingExpressionOfCandiate in bindingExpressions)
      {
        if (IsBindingValid(bindingSourceType, sourcePropertyName, bindingExpressionOfCandiate))
        {
          identifiedBindingTargets.Add(candidate);
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      bindingExpressions = new List<BindingExpression>();
      PropertyDescriptorCollection propertiesOfCandidate = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(candidate);
      foreach (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor in propertiesOfCandidate)
      {
        if (propertyDescriptor.IsReadOnly)
        {
          continue;
        }

        if (DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(propertyDescriptor) is DependencyPropertyDescriptor dependencyPropertyDescriptor)
        {
          DependencyProperty dependencyProperty = dependencyPropertyDescriptor.DependencyProperty;
          if (BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(candidate, dependencyProperty) is BindingExpression bindingExpressionOfCandiate)
          {
            ((IList<BindingExpression>)bindingExpressions).Add(bindingExpressionOfCandiate);

            if (IsBindingValid(bindingSourceType, sourcePropertyName, bindingExpressionOfCandiate))
            {
              identifiedBindingTargets.Add(candidate);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      this.bindingExpressionsMap.Add(candidate, bindingExpressions);
    }
  }

  bindingTargets = identifiedBindingTargets;

  return identifiedBindingTargets.Count > 0;
}

private static bool IsBindingValid(Type bindingSourceType, string sourcePropertyName, BindingExpression bindingExpression) 
  => bindingExpression.ResolvedSource.GetType() == bindingSourceType
    && bindingExpression.ResolvedSourcePropertyName.Equals(sourcePropertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal);

Then use it as follows:
// In this example RootPanel is a Grid, 
// the root element of the e.g. Window
IEnumerable<DependencyObject> bindingTargetCandidates = this.RootPanel.Children
  .Cast<DependencyObject>();
Type typeOfBindingSource = typeof(MyClass);
IEnumerable<string> propertyNamesOfBindingSource = typeOfBindingSource.GetProperties()
  .Select(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name);

foreach (string propertyName in propertyNamesOfBindingSource)
{
  if (TryGetBindingTargets(
    typeOfBindingSource, 
    propertyName, 
    bindingTargetCandidates, 
    out IEnumerable<DependencyObject> bindingTargets))
  {
    // Binding targets for the current binding source successfully found
  }
}

